# R: repeat elements of a list based on another list

Tags: r, list, repeat

I have searched for this but in vain.
the problem is I have two lists, first with the elements to be repeated
for example

```
my.list<-list(c('a','b','c','d'), c('g','h'))
```

and the second list is the number of times each element is to be repeated

```
repeat.list<-list(c(5,7,6,1), c(2,3))
```

I would like to create a new list in which each element in my.list is repeated based in repeat.list
i.e.
result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b"  "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "d" 
[[2]]
[1] "g" "g" "h" "h" "h"
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 8):

Use `mapply`:

```
mapply(rep, my.list, repeat.list)
[[1]]
 [1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "d"

[[2]]
[1] "g" "g" "h" "h" "h"
```

---

`lapply` also does the trick, but is more verbose:

```
lapply(seq_along(my.list), function(i)rep(my.list[[i]], repeat.list[[i]]))
[[1]]
 [1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "c" "d"

[[2]]
[1] "g" "g" "h" "h" "h"
```